# I use Python 3.6 on windows and I can't install numpy even using bash on ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, bash, numpy

I run Python 3.6 on windows and I can't install numpy even using bash on ubuntu for windows for installing it sudo apt-get install python3-numpy , it says actually that it has installed then running my code on python which imports numpy gives me the same error message : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Comment: You need to install the package, with `sudo pip3 install numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a separate python interpretor to run your program or directly from bash on ubuntu on windows?
Try this,firstly open bash on ubuntu on windows and  navigate to the directory where file is stored (using 'cd' command) and then use the python3 file_name.py to run your program. Also you can access your windows files from bash on windows after navigating to /mnt/c/ folder.